# Datepicker Format getDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I need to get the date as `yyyy-MM-dd`, but I always get in different formats. How can I get datepicker value as I want?

https://jsfiddle.net/041h6mss/

HTML:

```
<input id="thedate" type="text" />
<input type="button" id="button" value="submit" />
<span id="output"></span>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){

    $("#thedate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "D, M d, yy",
    });
})
var output = document.getElementById("output");

document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    output.innerHTML = $("#thedate").datepicker("getDate");
};
```

I get value as `Mon Apr 03 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)`, but I want it as `2017-03-03`

Comment: Are you using [Moment](https://momentjs.com/) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've updated answer. Check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/041h6mss/1/

HTML:

```
<input id="thedate" type="text" />
<input id="altField" type="hidden" />
<input type="button" id="button" value="submit" />
<span id="output"></span>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $("#thedate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "D, M d, yy",
        altField: "#altField",
        altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
})
var output = document.getElementById("output");

document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    output.innerHTML = $("#altField").val();
};
```

Alternatively, you may try this too (much better solution):

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    output.innerHTML = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", $("#thedate").datepicker("getDate"));
};
```

Comment: I prefer second one. Thank you for the quick solution!

Answer (score 1):

Your date format is incorrect, you need to change it to `yy-mm-dd`

```
$(function(){
    $("#thedate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
})
var output = document.getElementById("output");

document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    output.innerHTML = $("#thedate").datepicker("getDate");
};
```

Comment: I thought he wanted to keep `"D, M d, yy"` format in textbox and get preferred format in output.